# Windows Bash script gets exit without executing all commands

Tags: node.js, bash, jenkins

I'm executing a set of commands through Jenkins by Execute Windows Batch Command.

```
PUSHD %BASE_DIR%\Sivantos.Loyalty\Sivantos.Loyalty.Web.AdminPortal

npm install
ng build --prod
```

its executing the first command (npm install) and getting exit without executing the next command (ng build --prod) the same working fine if i try to manually run those.

help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `call` in windows,

Try using

```
@echo off
PUSHD %BASE_DIR%\Sivantos.Loyalty\Sivantos.Loyalty.Web.AdminPortal

call npm install
call ng build --prod
```

use `@echo off`, if you want to avoid these commands getting print to the command prompt